# PHP ORACLE Select ORA-00933 SQL Command Not Properly Ended

Tags: php, oracle, variables, select

I keep getting an ORA-00933 error on a query I am using to create a csv file using Ajax. I am returning a csv but it always contains the ORA-00933 error. I will link the PHP code below that is causing the error and then I will link the error. Thank you for the help.

```
<?php
$rangeD_Echo = $_POST["rangeD"];
$year_Echo = $_POST["year"];

$yearTruncation =  substr($year_Echo, 2);
$yearTruncationMinusOne = $yearTruncation-1;
$Start = '1-Oct-'.$yearTruncationMinusOne;
$End = '30-Sep-'.$yearTruncation;

if ($rangeD_Echo == 'Annual')
{
    $Start = '1-Oct-'.$yearTruncationMinusOne;
    $End = '30-Sep-'.$yearTruncation;
}
else if ($rangeD_Echo == 'Q1 FY')
{
    $Start = '1-Oct-'.$yearTruncationMinusOne;
    $End = '31-Dec-'.$yearTruncationMinusOne;   
}
else if ($rangeD_Echo == 'Q2 FY')
{
    $Start = '1-Jan-'.$yearTruncation;
    $End = '31-Mar-'.$yearTruncation;
}
else if ($rangeD_Echo == 'Q3 FY')
{
    $Start = '1-Apr-'.$yearTruncation;
    $End = '30-Jun-'.$yearTruncation;   
}
else if ($rangeD_Echo == 'Q4 FY')
{
    $Start = '1-Jul-'.$yearTruncation;
    $End = '30-Sep-'.$yearTruncation;
}


$Start = settype($Start, 'string');
$End = settype($End, 'string');
/*** CSV File Creation Land ***/
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=d-Report.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('Week Ending', 'No', 'Project Title', 'Project Contact', 
                       'Org', 'SNo', 'NNo', 'Verified By', 'Date Verified', 
                       'Comments', 'Notes'));

/*** connect to SQL DB ***/
$dbe = get_db_connection('db');
$dbe->connect();
/*** connect or ORACLE DB ***/
$db = oci_connect('QUERY','pw','server:1521/view');
if (!$db){
  $e = oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbview WHERE (STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED') AND PNUMBER <>' ' AND AMENDMENT_DATE_CREATED BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startT, dd-mm-yy) AND TO_DATE(:doneT, dd-mm-yy)
                                                                                                                    ORDER BY AMENDMENT_DATE_CREATED DESC";                                                                                                      
$runQuery = oci_parse($db, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($runQuery, ":startT", $Start);
oci_bind_by_name($runQuery, ":doneT", $End);
oci_execute($runQuery);

while($row = oci_fetch_array($runQuery, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{
    $WNumber = $row['PNUMBER']."-".$row['DNUMBER'];

    $querySQLDB = "SELECT [Verified_By], [Comments], [Notes], [Date_Verified] 
           FROM dbo.Information 
           WHERE dbo.Information.W_Key_ID = '$WNumber' 
           ORDER BY dbo.Information.ID DESC";
    $dbe->query($querySQLDB);
    $sqlData = $dbe->fetch();

    $dateNoTime = str_replace("12:00:00:000AM"," ",$sqlData['Date_Verified']);

    fputcsv($output, array($row['AMENDMENT_DATE_CREATED'], $WNumber, $row['TITLE'], $row['NAME'], 
                           $row['ORG'], $PNumber, $sqlData['Verified_By'], $dateNoTime,
                           $sqlData['Comments'], $sqlData['Notes']));

}
fclose($output);
echo $output;
?>
```

Error in CSV:

```
<b>Warning:</b><br/>oci_execute() [<a href='function.oci-execute'>function.oci-execute</a>]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended<br />
```

Comment: *Hm...* try escaping your input. The quotes are surely a sign of an injection which SQL is not agreeing with.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Hi Fred, thank you for the response, can you please provide a quick example of how to escape my input!

Comment: *You're welcome*. TBH, I don't know how escaping is done in Oracle or whether a PHP method can be used in conjunction with it, such as `real_escape_string()` and/or `stripslashes()`. But do see the answer given below. It could very well be the solution, being quotes `(:startT, 'dd-mm-yy')` and  `(:doneT, 'dd-mm-yy')` for the date.

Comment: @Fred-ii-So now that I added the 'dd-mm-yy' I have changed to a different error, an ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: You're welcome. I won't be able to assist any further. I'm a MySQL guy, not Oracle. But do Google the error, I saw many hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need single quotes enclosing the date format `TO_DATE(:startT, 'dd-mm-yy')`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbview
         WHERE (STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED')
          AND NUMBER <> ' '
          AND AMENDMENT_DATE_CREATED
        BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startT, 'dd-mm-yy')  AND TO_DATE(:doneT, 'dd-mm-yy')
        ORDER BY AMENDMENT_DATE_CREATED DESC";
```

And other query without `[]` in `SELECT`

```
  $querySQLDB = "SELECT Verified_By, Comments, Notes, Date_Verified 
           FROM dbo.Information 
           WHERE dbo.Information.W_Key_ID = '$WNumber' 
           ORDER BY dbo.Information.ID DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, so I did this and now I have a different warning it's a ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error. Please help and I will award the answer! Thanks so far.

Comment: @vector and `NUMBER` cannot be an actual column..?

Comment: The 1st query is where the error occurs. It actually shows up at the oci_execute($runQuery) so that infers that it's the $query that is causing the error! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry yeah it's not an actual column, I just changed some of the names of my columns when posting to the forum.

Comment: Perhaps, you missed something in your actual code. The query I have in answer is right.

Comment: @vector does it work removing the `ORDER BY` clause entirely?

Comment: no it does not work, removing the ORDER By gives me a new error an ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format.

Comment: I think you're right for some reason my JSON values are not being taken out when I do a $year_Echo = $_POST["yearPop"];